# Ajuda com código em Visualg

Tags: algoritmo, condição, portugol, visualg

Estou tentado fazer esse trecho do meu código funcionar

```
enquanto(n <> "s") e (n <> "n") faca
escreva("")
leia(n)
fimenquanto
```

mas ele retorna este erro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O `enquanto (...) faca` é similiar ao `while (...) do` das demais linguagens, verifique ademais se a síntaxe está correta. Além disso, o VisuAlg é repleto de bugs.

Em meus testes, apenas separando a condição do enquanto, o código rodou.
Segue código:

```
enquanto (n <> "s") e (n <> "n") faca
  escreva("Texto de Teste")
  leia(n)
fimenquanto
```

Comment: Obrigado foi isso mesmo do espaço no meu eu fiz enquanto(  , mais era enquanto ( , era só separa o parentese.